# NoMethodError for defined scope in ActionView

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Template model I have

```
# models/template.rb
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recent, -> { order('created_at DESC') }
end
```

I try to make the following call:

```
# views/template/_template_sidebar.haml
- Template.recent.each do |template|
  %h2= template.title
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `recent' for ActionView::Template:Class
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? Is there a better if I use an instance variable instead? I'm avoiding the latter suggestion because I feel it creates an additional layer of complexity.

Comment: try reload sercer or console and try it againe

Comment: Can you post your model code in the question?

Comment: Can you post the `_post_sidebar.haml` code as well?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try restarting the server and check.

Comment: Wait, what? `ActionView::Post`? How on Earth did that get defined?

Comment: Is it meant to be @posts.recent.each?..as in posts plural?

Comment: Try using `::Post` instead of `Post`. That should get you working now, but I wonder where did that class even come from.

Comment: ::Post.recent worked. I seems off though, it doesn't sound idiomatic. Not sure either where that class come from.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't post it. It's not an answer really, it's a workaround. Let's start investigating. Use `pry` (gem) and do a `binding.pry` inside a view, then do `show-source Post` in the prompt you get. See what that gives you.

Comment: It begins with

`From: /Users/martinverdejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/post.rb @ line 7:`
`Class name: ActionView::Post`
`Number of lines: 329`

`class Post
  extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
...
end`
and a long class definition follows, which does not include any of the ActiveRecord scopes. Am I looking for something in particular @D-side?

Comment: The file path is something... **It doesn't exist where it tells it's from!** [See here](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v4.2.1/actionview/lib/action_view). Something is seriously wrong. Well, never hurts to try classic fixes... Tried rebooting? :)

Comment: Yes. Though I might have found the [problem](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Template.html). For brevity I used `post` in my question but my actual code is on `/models/templates.rb`. I'm assuming my model name is a reserved class name. Bigger problem if I have to rename the model. I might just stick with the work around. Didn't know `Template` is reserved when I started this project. What do you think @D-side?

Comment: `Template`? Ha! Now that makes perfect sense. Well, then you got no choice but using `::Template`, assuming you don't want to move the class.  Update the question to reflect your real class name then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Well... the situation got a bit sticky.

You have your own `Template` class. But there is also `ActionView::Template`.

A view is executed in context of an `ActionView` instance (you can verify that by doing `binding.pry` inside it and looking at `self`). When you use a bare `Template` there Ruby looks it up in closest scopes, going up from the one you're in (`ActionView`).

Hence, it looks up `ActionView` first, resulting in `ActionView::Template` popping up instead. **Oops.**

To resolve this, assuming you don't want to do anything with your current class, is to explicitly specify "`Template` from the root scope", `::Template` that is.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `Template` should be a reserved class name due to [this previously existing rails class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Template.html). As a workaround I used the following call instead.

```
 - ::Template.recent.each do |template|
  %h1= template.title
```

Thanks to @D-side for the suggestion in the comments.